# Translating IPTables rule to UFW

Tags: mysql, iptables, firewall, ufw, openswan

we are using an Ubuntu 12.04 x64 LTS VPS. Firewall being used is UFW.
I have setup a Varnish + LEMP setup. along with other things, including an Openswan IPSEC VPN from our office to the VPS data center. A second in house Ubuntu box is to act as MySQL slave and fetch data from the VPS through the VPN.

Master's ppp0 is seen as 10.1.2.1 from the slave, they ping etc.

I have done the various required tasks but I can't get the client (slave) MySQL (nor telnet 10.1.2.1 3306) to access the master through the VPN unless I issue this fairly obvious IPTables command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.1.2.0/24 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

I willingly forced the accepted input to come from the last octet.
*With this rule everything works just fine!*

However I want to translate this command to UFW syntax so to keep everything in one place.

Now I admit being inexperienced with UFW, I prepared rules like:

```
ufw allow proto tcp from 10.1.2.0/24 port mysql
```

and 2-3 variations involving specifying 3306 instead of mysql, specifying a target IP (MySQL's my.cnf at the moment is configured as 0.0.0.0) and similar but I just don't seem to be able to replicate the simple iptables rule in a functional way.

Anyone could kindly give me a suggestion that is not to dump UFW?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
ufw allow proto tcp from 10.1.2.0/24 port mysql
```

adds the following to iptables

```
iptables -L ufw-user-input -vn
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
   pkts bytes target   prot opt in    out  source       destination

    0   0     ACCEPT   tcp  --   *     *   10.1.2.0/24  0.0.0.0/0    tcp spt:3306
```

note the `spt` this says the source port of the packet needs to be 3306. You need to tell UFW to allow packets with a destination of port 3306.

```
ufw allow proto tcp from 10.1.2.0/24 to any port mysql
```

which adds a rule like this

```
iptables -L ufw-user-input -vn
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
   pkts bytes target   prot opt in    out  source       destination

    0   0     ACCEPT   tcp  --   *     *   10.1.2.0/24  0.0.0.0/0    tcp dpt:3306
```

which will allow packets destined to port 3306 from 10.1.2.0/24.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked flawlessy! When I get more rep I will come back here to upvote you.